# Line count using map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have couple thousand files drop to a directory from other people each day, each files is around 400MB to 1GB big.

I want to count the total number of lines in the directory.

I was planning to do map reduce like the following

Mapper

```
public static class LineMapper
        extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        context.write("static_key", one);
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
public static class IntSumReducer
        extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}
```

But after thinking about it, I feel that the reducer nodes are going to get overwhelmed since there is only 1 key.

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Why are you using mapreduce for this? Do you have Pig or Spark?

Comment: For the word count, you can simply do it by doing a cat on HDFS something like this, hdfs dfs -cat /path/somefile.csv | wc -l will give the #lines

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use mapreduce for this, then the best option is to use counters. Change your mapper to something like this and set number of reducers to 0.

```
public static class LineMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        enum MyCounters {
            TOTAL_COUNT;
        }


        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                 context.getCounter(MyCounters.TOTAL_COUNT).increment(1L);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me, how to get the value of this counter in reduce function? If I try to get it by `context.getCounter(MyCounters.TOTAL_COUNT).getValue();`, it gives me 0. Basically, how can I transfer value of this counter from `map` to `reduce`?

Answer (score 1):

This might be quicker to do via `Hive`. Outlining one possible approach below:

**Create a HDFS directory to hold the data**

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir /hive-data
$ hadoop fs -mkdir /hive-data/linecount
```

**Create a Hive table**

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE linecount
(
  line string
)
LOCATION
  'hdfs:///hive-data/linecount'
```

**Load data files in HDFS**

```
$ hadoop fs -put a.txt hdfs:///hive-data/linecount
$ hadoop fs -put b.txt hdfs:///hive-data/linecount
$ hadoop fs -put c.txt hdfs:///hive-data/linecount
```

**Count via Hive query**

```
hive> select count(*) from linecount;
```

Comment: I prefer this option as it doesn't involve writing, compiling and deploying a MapReduce job.